# TaxonomyFieldValueCollection elements order

Tags: taxonomy, metadata

Does multivalued taxonomy field return elements in the same order as entered by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it returns in the same order as shown in the input field

Comment: Many thanks, Robert! But it would be great if you could point me to any documentation or other source where you got this information from. I tried to find it, but with  no success.

Comment: Well, the source is that I have tested it multiple times...

Comment: They're saved in a (hidden) text field and the order is maintained, like this: English|c61d9028-824f-446e-9389-eb9515813a42;#French|de1d9028-824f-556e-9389-ac9515813a56